# Why is VS2015 skipping lines while using Step Over (F10) in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

When using Visual Studio Emulator for Android some lines are skipped when I try to go from line to line.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ApplicationUnhandledExceptionHandler;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += UnobservedTaskExceptionHandler;
```

The above lines are skipped on emulator, but not on device. I'm inspecting this, because a handler is not called on emulator. I tried to set the breakpoint directly without success.

What is the reason for line skipping in debug mode?

Comment: Are you sure the code you are executing is the same as what you are debugging?

Comment: There's a setting in the Debug settings that controls it...evidently, property gets/sets can be thought of as "noise" and skipped.

Comment: Are you able to break with a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes Android deployment gets confused - breakpoints fail to trigger (they usually show as open circles in the editor gutter, which indicates source mismatch), the app doesn't run the way you expect, etc.

When the IDE shows code that disagrees with what your device or simulator is doing, then I have found that forcing an uninstall of the package and then redeploying from the IDE usually resolves it. This can be done most reliably by using the ADB command prompt and running `"adb uninstall com.company.packagename"`. After that, just rebuild and deploy/run the app again from the IDE as you normally would.

Comment: Yes, uninstalling the app in the simulator was the solution. Don't know why it got out of sync, because I've made a clean and rebuild.

Comment: It seems to happen to me randomly on occasion, but it will almost always happen if I add/remove a package dependency or if I switch between debug/release build targets.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that in visual studio 2015 go to `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General` ensure `Enable .NET Framework source stepping` is checked.

Rebuild after and you should be good to go.