# Debugger moving randomly

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, debugging

My solution contains many project and I am debugging that. Few days back it was working fine but now when I debug it is moving randomly, means when I press <kbd>F10</kbd> it is not going to next line but any random line.

- I am not using multithreading.
- I tried cleaning solution.
- Tried re-starting VS.
- Tried re-starting computer.
- Ensured application is not running optimized code.
- Tried checking/Unchecking "skip over property/operator" checkbox under Tools > Debugging.
- Confirm current project (one being debugged using Configuration: Active(Debug) and Platform: Active(Any CPU))
- Ensured only one instance of application is running.

Now what could be the reason?

Comment: Why are you using F10 when F11 is the one for stepping into?

Comment: @AsheraH I just want to step over

Comment: @Imad Try deleting temp files

Comment: @ADarnal not working

Comment: I suppose you have checked your hotkeys? Perhaps they got changed for some reason.

Comment: @Reality-Torrent Checked it, step over is F10 only

Comment: @Imad Try this. Goto : Tools->Options->Debugging->General->check "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"or "Use Native Compatibility Mode" or both.

Comment: @Imad，if you create a simple app, whether it still has this issue if you debug it? If just the specific solution has this issue, I suggest you create a blank solution, and then add all project files to the new blank solution, clean and build the solution, debug it again. If just the specific app has this issue, you'd better to check your output windows, maybe you could get useful information like this case which was related to project deployment or others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551694/why-is-vs2015-skipping-lines-while-using-step-over-f10-in-debug-mode